# Javascript append array into object with key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data like this:

```
[{ team: 'Team1',
     wins: 1,
     group: GroupA
},{ team: 'Team2',
     wins: 1,
     group: GroupA
},{ team: 'Team3',
     wins: 1,
     group: GroupB
},{ team: 'Team4',
     wins: 1,
     group: GroupB
}]
```

I want it in this form (I basically want to group the data by some value, in this case "group" and use that value as a key in an object of arrays):

```
{ GroupA: [{'Team1', wins: 1, group: GroupA},{'Team2', wins: 1, group: GroupA}],
GroupB: [{'Team3', wins: 1, group: GroupB},{'Team4', wins: 1, group: GroupB}]
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Here is what I tried and which almost worked, but returns objects:

```
var newStats = {}
     arrTeamStats.map(function(key,idx){

                var arr = [];

                if(newStats[key.group] == undefined) {
                    arr = key;
                    newStats[key.group] = arr;
                } else {
                else {
                    group = key.group;
                    newStats[group].push(key);
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're misunderstanding `.map()`. It's not a general purpose iterator, but rather is used to create a new array from the content of an existing one.

What you can do is simply iterate and add new properties to an object as they're located, and consolidate the content.

```js
var data = [{ team: 'Team1',wins: 1,group: "GroupA"},{ team: 'Team2',wins: 1,group: "GroupA"},{ team: 'Team3',wins: 1,group: "GroupB"},{ team: 'Team4',wins: 1,group: "GroupB"}];

var result = {};
for (const o of data) {
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(o.group)) result[o.group].push([o]);
  else result[o.group] = [[o]];
}

console.log(result);
```

---

Or a little more concise like this:

```js
var data = [{ team: 'Team1',wins: 1,group: "GroupA"},{ team: 'Team2',wins: 1,group: "GroupA"},{ team: 'Team3',wins: 1,group: "GroupB"},{ team: 'Team4',wins: 1,group: "GroupB"}];

var result = {};
for (const o of data) result[o.group] = (result[o.group] || []).concat([[o]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can I tweak this to get { "GroupA":  [{ "team": "Team1", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupA" }], [{ "team": "Team2", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupA" }], "GroupB": [{ "team": "Team3", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupB" }], [{ "team": "Team4", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupB" }] }

Comment: @mo_maat: That's the result it currently gives. I'm not seeing any difference. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: It's maybe hard to notice but it is different.  I need separate arrays for the elements within the group: So `GroupA: [{element1}], [{element2}]` instead of `GroupA: [{element1}, {element2}]`

Comment: Oh, I see. That won't work because it's not a valid structure. You'd need to wrap each individual array in an array that holds them all. `{ "GroupA": [[{ "team": "Team1", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupA" }], [{ "team": "Team2", "wins": 1, "group": "GroupA" }]], "GroupB": ...`

Comment: ... `GroupA: [[{element1}], [{element2}]], GroupB: ...`

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I need to do then.  I need to be able to loop through each object's array.  The structure you suggested will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163217/discussion-between-mo-maat-and-rock-star).

Answer (score 4):

You need to `reduce` your array to return an `Object`.

```
arrTeamStats.reduce(function(h, o) {
  h[o.group] = h[o.group] || []
  h[o.group].push(o)
  return h
}, {})
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention I want a vanilla javascript solution.  I don't mind some of the newer syntax but I want to the plain one too.

Comment: Changed. Force of habit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inclined to use something like Lodash, you could use `_.groupBy` as follows:

```js
var input = [{ team: 'Team1',
     wins: 1,
     group: 'GroupA'
},{ team: 'Team2',
     wins: 1,
     group: 'GroupA'
},{ team: 'Team3',
     wins: 1,
     group: 'GroupB'
},{ team: 'Team4',
     wins: 1,
     group: 'GroupB'
}];

var output = _.groupBy(input, 'group');
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```